# Counting lattice paths using all four directions

Tags: combinatorics

Without loss of generality, assume $c,d\geq 0$. I want to count the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(c,d)$ using paths in all four directions N, S, E, W in $n$ steps. The answer is supposed to be $n\choose \frac{n-c-d}{2}$ $n\choose \frac{n+c-d}{2}$.

I can see that the first term comes from choosing the number of places to go "backwards" when heading towards $(c,d)$ from the origin, i.e. we have $\frac{n-c-d}{2}$ many steps that are W or S out of $n$ steps total. I don't see where the second term comes from. The proof outlined [here](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kratt/artikel/paths.html) says (image below) that there is a bijection between the set of paths we're counting and the set of pairs of NS-paths from the origin to $(0,c+d)$ and from the origin to $(0,c-d)$. I don't see why this is a bijection. Could anyone please explain?

(Or if you have another way of explaining this formula, that would help too.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This bijection comes from a change of coordinates. A drawing will explain this better than words.

[image]

We want to take steps accordingly to the two directions above. Considering the drawing below, we decompose each elementary step in one movement in the up-right direction and one movement in the up-left direction, the two taking place at the same time. Thus a path in the first drawing corresponds to two "parallel" paths in one dimension.

[image]

An other explanation: Let $(x,y)$ be the coordinates of the point where we are at. We identify our position by $T=(x+y, x-y)$ instead of $(x,y)$. Each step modifies $T$ by $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$. We make $n$ steps and in the end we want to have $T=(c+d, c-d)$.

But this is a curiosity that only happens in two dimensions.